# Error while masking in Informatica DB2 AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, informatica, informatica-powercenter, db2-400, iseries-navigator

My requirement here is masking DB2 tables in AS400 iSeries. i have connected through Datadirect ODBC driver. I know INFA doesnot encourage ODBC connections. but still, in this case PWX is not an option for the client. so, i have source and target connections successful in Powercenter as well as TDM. Also, imported the sources. but, facing an error while running masking job. below is the error. Any help here is greatly appreciated!

RR_4035 : SQL Error [
FnName: Execute -- [Informatica][ODBC DB2 Wire Protocol driver][UDB DB2 for iSeries and AS/400]NN5SOGS9.NNA1DF00 IS AN UNDEFINED NAME.  TABLE].

BLKR_16004 : ERROR: Prepare failed.

NN5SOGS9 --> USERNAME FOR DB,
NNA1DF00 --> TABLE IN DB

I don't know Why its taking USER.Table instead of Schema.Table

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I think you defined schema name in session level. Edit the session, go to source and set the correct schema. Looks like it can not access that  table.

Comment: Standard SQL will default to {username}.table if schema is not specified in the statement. DB2 for i can be accessed either through standard SQL or through library list depending on how you configure your connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I resolved the above by using PWX instead of ODBC drivers for connectivity.